# Link address shows when I hover, but is not clickable

Tags: html, shopify, href

Using 'Prestige' theme on Shopfiy, but doubt that that is relevant.

I am trying to make it so that when a user clicks on this video container, it directs them to the link.

I finally got the link to correctly attach to the block, so when I go to click on it, the link appears in the bottom left hand of my screen (see photo).

BUT I can't actually click it??

What is my code missing?

```
<a href="https://www.clarasunwoo.com/collections/best-sellers">
<section class="Section" id="section-{{ section.id }}" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="background-video" data-section-settings='{{ section_settings }}'>
  <span class="ImageHero {% if section.settings.section_size != 'normal' %}ImageHero--{{ section.settings.section_size }}{% endif %}" "display:block" >
    <span class="ImageHero__VideoHolder"></span>
  </span>
</section>
</a>
```

[visible link address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyQLD.png)

Comment: On website it working fine, what is the issue on your side?